# Difficulty Loading Modules with Require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to load and use a module I defined with Require. As far as I can tell, I'm following the patterns on the official site, but I'm not getting the loaded module inside the require call.

main.js:

```
define(function (require) {
    require(['./util'], function(util){
       util.dictionary(); 
    });
    ...
});
```

util.js:

```
define(function(){
    "use strict";

    var util = {};
    ...
    return util;
});
```

With this, util.dictionary() fails because util is undefined.

Both files are on the same directory level, and I haven't defined any baseURL for Require.

Why is this failing?

Comment: As a side note, I've already looked at a bunch of other answered questions. Nothing helpful. I'm either already doing what the answer suggests, or the recommended solution hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of poking around, I discovered that Chrome was using a cached versions of some of my files, and clearing the cache caused the modules to load correctly.

Yes, I'm a web development noob.